# Reading the content of a received calendar invite

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a script that read and process calendar invites received on my e-mail account.

Problem is that:

```
//there is only one message that is the result of this filter, and it contains a calendar invite
var threads = GmailApp.search('is:unread from:xxx@yyy.com has:attachment',0,10);
var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
var attachments = msgs[0][0].getAttachments();
```

attachments = 0, meaning that while the gmail filter considers that a calendar invite is an attachment and filters it correctly, Google Apps Scripts apparently does not consider calendar invites as an attachment.

How to programmatically read a e-mail that has a calendar invite?

Best,

OP

Comment: Calandar invites from google are different from outlook. Outlook invites vary in structure depending on which exchange server they pass through. that's just two systems.;

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I should have no problem parsing and processing the invites in different formats, but I am having trouble in being able to read the invites in apps script.

Comment: Point being that it is hard to define reliable search criteria to get them which is why that matters before worrying about parsing. Not all have attachments. many are sent as multi-part. Or is your question about a known consistent source?

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem getting a Calendar invite as an attachment using Apps script. Your code:

```
function getCalAttach() { 
   var threads = GmailApp.search('is:unread from:s@steve.thevoxbox.info has:attachment',0,10);
   var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
   var attachments = msgs[0][0].getAttachments();
   var readAtt = attachments[0].getDataAsString();
   Logger.log(readAtt);
}
```

Logs the attachment with no problem, and I can retrieve the data as a string. This worked for me using both Gmails native calendar, and when searching for an invite from another mail system.

[image: Logging Output]

Comment: At least one Microsoft Outlook invitation that has been through an MS - Exchange Server does not show up using your (or my) code. That is weird. I will send you an invite to see if you get the same results. I will also explore using the google calendar v3 api in google apps scripts to see if I can get the most recent calendar entries using that api (google apps scripts calendar objects apparently does not let me do that).

Comment: i mentioned that possibility. i have been through all this pain myself :( sometimes calendar invites are within a multipart message encoded in base64 - not much you do to find those.

Comment: So i changed my strategy and now I am using Google to parse the invites, and I read the data I need using the Calendar API. Still very hard to get the data the way I need (example: could not yet get the events sorted by most recently edited or created), but it is a progress